# in jigsaw puzzle game in game score how can identified using moves and remaining time

Tags: android

i am implementing puzzle game app in android  . in this application one level complete then get score number of moves and remaining level completion on time .i am level completed show in dialogbox it shows  move next level ,then number of moves and remaining time in each level value display in these dialog box 
todisplay (number of moves + remaing time)...

((TextView)findViewById(R.id.MovesTextView)).setText("Moves-"+moves);
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.ScoreTextView1)).setText("Time-"+(time/(1000*60))+":"+((time%(1000*60))/1000));

how can implemented  this problem  please forward some solution  its urgent

Comment: What is the problem? What programing language is this?

Comment: this is puzzle game in android game over find game score this score related into (number of moves and remaining time)

Comment: can you give me the step how to create a jigsaw puzzle game in android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to make the score a function of remaining time and total moves? So the problem is to find the algorithm `f(time, moves)`.

Scoring is not usually an exact science. You could work this out mathematically, but the best solution is a fair one; give players a score for completing the level, then give a bonus proportional to how good they are compared to other players.

To gather this data lots of play-testers of different skill levels must play the game lots of times each. Record information like `average time per move`, `total number of moves` and `time remaining`, then graph this data. Once you understand the shape of this data, you will have the information required to make a fair `f(time, moves)`

A naive solution would be just something like this:

```
level_score = level * 100;
max_bonus = 100000;
bonus_score = max_bonus / (time_taken + moves_taken + level*10);
score = level_score + bonus_score;
```

Comment: thank u very much davidson forward this response .this functionality i am implementing.